# my links in my div need different properties

Tags: html, css

I have 2 sets of links

the list links - vertically listed
the image links - also vertically listed

I need the image links to be horizontally listed across the bottom

how would I do this?
I've tried display: inline; in css but what i need is something that overrides the a properties listed in the list links

How would I do that?

Here is some code

HTML

```
<body>

  <div id="sidebar" class= "container text-center col-lg-3">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="experience.html">Experience<a/></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div style="margin-left:0%">
        <a href="https://github.com/evie4411" target="_blank"><img src="./images/iconmonstr-github-1.png"></a>
        <a href="https://github.com/evie4411" target="_blank"><img src="./images/iconmonstr-linkedin-4.png"></a>
        <a href="https://github.com/evie4411" target="_blank"><img src="./images/iconmonstr-twitter-4.png"></a>
      </div>
```

css

```
a, li{
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: table;
}


img {
  max-width: 25px;
  max-height: 25px;
  display: inline;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a different CSS selector for the first set of links, so it doesn't affect the second set of image links.

```
li,
li a {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: table;
}
```

The change above `li, li a` makes the CSS target only the `a` links that are descendants of an `li` list item.

Since the second set of links aren't descendants of `li` list items, they won't have the styles above applied to them.

Alternatively, you might want to add a CSS class to the `ul` (i.e. `<ul class="top-links">...</ul>`) and a different one to the `div` surrounding the image links (i.e. `<div class="image-links">...</div>`). This will allow to to target them in your CSS in a manner that is easier to understand and less likely to overlap:

```
li, 
.top-links a { ... }

.image-links img { ... }
```